# What variant of JSON Schema is Google Sheets API's JSON resource?

Tags: json, google-sheets-api, jsonschema

I have been looking at the [Google Sheets API v4 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets). I noticed that it was JSON, but when I copied it into my IDE, I got errors because it used "primatives" such as `string` , `number`, `enum(...)`, and `object(...)`. JSON doesn't support these; therefore it isn't pure JSON.

After some research, I determined that it was `JSON Schema`; however, that must not be fully what the following code snippet it as JSON Schema doesn't seem to support `object(...)` and `enum(...)`

**So what form of JSON Schema is this?** I am unable to identify beyond `JSON Schema`.

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
    object(SpreadsheetProperties)
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      object(Sheet)
    }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object(NamedRange)
    }
  ],
  "spreadsheetUrl": string,
  "developerMetadata": [
    {
      object(DeveloperMetadata)
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what `NamedRange` is...

```
{
  "namedRangeId": string,
  "name": string,
  "range": {
    object(GridRange)
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are seeing here is not JSON Schema. I can assure you. What was your source for suspecting it might be JSON Schema?

Comment: It's a way for Google to link you to the appropriate pages that describe each collection of properties. It's nice for documentation as you don't have to update every single page with a changed specification, you just update the changed but and the rest are complete since they link to it instead of including it inline

Comment: @Relequestual I was doing some Googling about primitives for JSON values. I found [this page on JSON Schema types](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html). I took a quick look and noticed that it matched fairly well without going in-depth (except for object and enum support). I should have just said **What for of JSON is this?**

Comment: @tehhowch it has a defined structure and is well-formed. Either it's a Google proprietary JSON format or its public with a name.

Comment: I haven't seen it before, so I'm guessing it's a proprietary format.